# Local Server Mac OSX 10.5

Tags: macos, webserver, local

I'm using a legacy version of OSX (10.5) and want to find out how to develop locally using the built-in Apache server. I have turned on web sharing and am able to access the local website at: http://my.ip.address. However, I cannot find out where to save my index.html so that it will be accessible at http://my.ip.address.

I have found instructions online, but most are for Mountain Lion and reference a "Web Server" directory that isn't on my machine. My question is: "Where do I save my index.html to view it locally at my IP address?" Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be at /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html. Note that this is the Library folder at the top level of your startup volume, not the one in your home folder. Also, IIRC by default there are language-localized index files there by default (e.g. index.html.en), and you'll need to remove or replace those.